# TreeView in Grid gives "Unexpected token :"

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a Telerik Grid with a Telerik TreeView in an EditorTemplate that pops up when an edit button is pressed, but the Grid's onEdit() event doesn't get triggered unless i comment out the TreeView.

Google Chrome's debugger says: "Uncaught syntaxError: Unexpected token :"

Telerik Grid:

```
@{
Html.Telerik().Grid<SuperUserViewModel>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(x => x.Id))
    .ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Text)
                                 .Text("Opret superbruger"))



    .Columns(column =>
        {
            column.Bound(x => x.UserInitials);
            column.Command(commands =>
                {
                    commands.Edit();
                    commands.Delete();
                });


        })

    .DetailView(x => x.ClientTemplate("<ul><# for (var i = 0; i < Organizations.length; i++) { if(Organizations[i].IsChecked != false){#>"
                                      + "<li><#= Organizations[i].Name #></li>"
                                      + "<# }} #></ul>"))
    .EnableCustomBinding(true)
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
                                           .Select("SelectAjaxEditing", "SuperUser")
                                           .Delete("DeleteAjaxEditing", "SuperUser")
                                           .Update("SaveAjaxEditing", "SuperUser")
                                           .Insert("InsertAjaxEditing", "SuperUser"))
    .Pageable(paging => paging.Style(GridPagerStyles.Numeric | GridPagerStyles.PageSizeDropDown)
                              .Position(GridPagerPosition.Bottom))
    .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
    .ClientEvents(events => events.OnDataBinding("test").OnEdit("OnEdit"))
    .NoRecordsTemplate("Ingen brugere")
    .Render();
 }
```

Telerik TreeView:

```
@(Html.Telerik().TreeView()

         .Name("organizations")
         .ShowCheckBox(true)
         .BindTo((IEnumerable)ViewData["organizationsAll"], mappings =>
             {
                 mappings.For<OrganizationViewModel>(binding => binding
                                                                    .ItemDataBound((current, org) =>
                                                                        {
                                                                            current.Text = org.Name;
                                                                            current.Value = org.Id.ToString();
                                                                            current.Checked = org.IsChecked;
                                                                            current.Expanded = true;
                                                                        })
                                                                    .Children(org => org.Organizations));
             }))
```

Chrome Debugger:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : telerik.grid.editing.min.js:1146
b.grid.FormViewBinder.evaluatetelerik.grid.editing.min.js:1146
(anonymous function)telerik.grid.editing.min.js:1181
e.extend.proxy.gjquery-1.7.1.min.js:538
e.extend.eachjquery-1.7.1.min.js:480
e.fn.e.eachjquery-1.7.1.min.js:345
(anonymous function)telerik.grid.editing.min.js:1180
e.extend.proxy.gjquery-1.7.1.min.js:538
e.extend.eachjquery-1.7.1.min.js:476
b.grid.FormViewBinder.bindtelerik.grid.editing.min.js:1179
b.editing.implementation.editRowtelerik.grid.editing.min.js:868
(anonymous function)telerik.grid.editing.min.js:573
a.telerik.stopAlltelerik.common.min.js:1
f.event.dispatchjquery-1.7.1.min.js:1183
f.event.add.h.handle.ijquery-1.7.1.min.js:1103
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using another api to make the treeview?